# Missing nodes in creation of ordered linked list?

Tags: c++, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to create an ordered doubly-linked-list out of an already existing one by traversing its nodes and adding them via `add_ordered()`, however when I print the ordered list few nodes are missing.

`list.h`:

```
#ifnded LIST_H
#define LIST_H

struct Node {
// data member
    std::string value;
// constructors
    Node (std::string v) : value(v) { }
   Node (const Node& src) : value(src.value) { }
// overloaded operators
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Node& g);
    friend bool operator< (const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs);
    friend bool operator> (const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs);
};
//====================================================================================
// doubly linkes list accepting any object type as its data member (value)
template<class T>
class Link {
public:
    // public data member
    T value;

    // constructor
    Link<T> (T v, Link<T>* p = 0, Link<T>* s = 0) : value(v), prev(p), succ(s) { }
    // copy constructor
    Link<T> (const Link<T>& l) : value(l.value), prev(l.next()), succ(l.previous()) { }

    // non-modifying members
    Link<T>* next () const { return succ; }
    Link<T>* previous () const { return prev; }

    // modifying members
    Link<T>* insert (Link<T>* n);
    Link<T>* add (Link<T>* n);
    Link<T>* add_ordered (Link<T>* n);
private:
    // private data members
    Link<T>* prev;
    Link<T>* succ;
};
#include "list.cpp"
#endif
```

`list.cpp`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Node& g) {
    os << g.value ;
    return os;
}

bool operator< (const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs) {
    return lhs.value < rhs.value;
}

bool operator> (const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs) {
    return lhs.value > rhs.value;
}
//=======================================================================================

// It inserts the node passed as a parameter before the node currently pointed to by this.
template<class T>
Link<T>* Link<T>::insert (Link<T>* n) {
    if (!n) return this;
    if (!this) return n;

    n->succ = this;
    n->prev = prev;
    if (prev) prev->succ = n;
    prev = n;

    return n;
}

// It inserts the node passed as a parameter after the node currently pointer to by this.
template<class T>
Link<T>* Link<T>::add (Link<T>* n) {
    if (!n) return this;
    if (!this) return n;

    // n->succ = nullptr;
    n->succ = succ;
    n->prev = this;
    succ = n;

    return n;
}

/*
    It inserts the new node such that 
    current node and new node in
    lexicographical order; returns 
    pointer to last node. 

    First node in ordered list contains the 
    lexicographically smaller value.

    It assumes argument is the tail.
*/
template<class T>
Link<T>* Link<T>::add_ordered (Link<T>* n) {
    if (!n) return this;
    if (!this) { std::cout <<"new node first\n"; return n; }

    Link<T>* tail = this; 
    if (n->value > tail->value) {
        std::cout <<"new node largest \n";
        add(n); // add after current (last) node
        return n;
    }

    Link<T>* current_node = this; 
    while (current_node) {
        if (n->value > current_node->value) {
            std::cout <<"new node spliced \n";
            add(n);
            return tail;
        }
        std::cout <<"advance to head\n";
        current_node = current_node->previous();
    } 

    insert(n); // insert before current (first) node
    std::cout << "new node smallest\n";
    return tail;
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list.h>

template<class T>
void create_ordered_list (Link<T>* src, Link<T>*& dest) {
    while (src){    
        Link<T> l(src->value, nullptr, nullptr);
        dest = dest->add_ordered(new Link<T>(l));
        src = src->next();
    }  
}

template<class T>
void print(Link<T>* n) {
    Link<T>* tail = n;

    if (tail->next()) {
        std::cout <<"[";
        while (tail) {
            std::cout << tail->value;
            if (tail = tail->next()) std::cout <<"\n";
        }
        std::cout <<"]";
    } else if (tail->previous()) {
        std::cout <<"[";
        while (tail) {
            std::cout << tail->value;
            if (tail = tail->previous()) std::cout <<"\n";
        }
        std::cout <<"]";
    }
    getchar();
}
//===============================================================
int main () {
    Link<Node>* head = new Link<Node>(Node("Zeus"));
    head = head->insert(new Link<Node>(Node("Hera")));
    head = head->insert(new Link<Node>(Node("Athena")));
    head = head->insert(new Link<Node>(Node("Ares")));
    head = head->insert(new Link<Node>(Node("Poseidon")));

    print<Node>(head);

    std::cout <<"\nOrdered lists\n";
    Link<Node>* ordered_list = nullptr;
    create_ordered_list(head, ordered_list);
    print(ordered_list);
}
```

Output after the ordering:

> [Zeus
>   Hera 
>   Athena]

Expected output:

> [Zeus
>   Poseidon
>   Hera 
>   Athena
>   Ares]

---

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/wIt4O5)

Comment: `add` doesn't make `this->succ->prev` to point to `n`, thus breaking the list's invariants.

Comment: I've modified it including `succ->prev = n;` in `add()`, still no difference. Check the live example.

Comment: A call to `add_ordered` returns a pointer to some node in the middle of the list. You set `dest` to this pointer, thus effectively forgetting all the nodes to the left of it in the list (since you treat `dest` as the new head).

Comment: That is why I've included that line `Link<T>* tail = this;` in the beginning of `add_ordered()`, so that if the new node in not at the end and before I start traversing I have the tail to return it. The function always returns the last node.

Comment: You have a loop involving `current_node` - but you don't actually use `current_node` for anything. In this loop, you call `add(n)` - which adds the node after `this`, not after `current_node`. After that, `tail == this` is no longer the last node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to correct the `add()` function:

```
template<class T>
Link<T>* Link<T>::add (Link<T>* n) {
    ...
    n->succ = succ;
    n->prev = this;
    succ = n;   
    if (n->succ) n->succ->prev = n; ///!!!

    return n;
}
```

Then you have to intervert some `add()` and `insert()` in the `add_ordered()` function and adjust some returns:

```
template<class T>
Link<T>* Link<T>::add_ordered (Link<T>* n) {
    if (!n) return this;
    if (!this) { std::cout <<"new node first\n"; return n; }

    Link<T>* tail = this; 
    if (n->value > tail->value) {
        std::cout <<"new node largest \n";
        return insert(n); // No: you need to insert before current node !!!
    }

    Link<T>* current_node = this; 
    while (current_node) {
        if (n->value > current_node->value) {
            std::cout <<"new node spliced \n";
            add(n);
            return this;
        }
        std::cout <<"advance to head\n";
        current_node = current_node->previous();
    } 

    add(n); // no: here we have to add at the end !
    std::cout << "new node smallest\n";
    return this;
}
```

Then it should work:  [live demo](http://ideone.com/wIt4O5).

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! Last hours have been difficult :)

Comment: I guess now `tail` should be renamed to `head`, as now, every time we return the first node, right ? The list grows forward.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis exactly !  And this made your issue difficult to spot:  when I first read tail,and saw the add(), everything seemed rather logical ;-)